# Number format in ZKOSS label

Tags: zk, label

is there any way to format number in ZK label component that looks like like 
`<label value="${each.value}" />` ? Values are doubles and I want to separate thousands etc... I know that doublebox for example has format property but what if I just want to display number as label? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Feature Request**

First of all I have opened a feature request for this on ZK's tracking system you can find it [here](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-1047). Please follow this if you want updates.

**Ways of implementing**

There are in fact ways of implementing this depending on what pattern & techniques you are using.

**MVC & EL**

You can create an EL function which will do the formatting for you in your ZUL file. First of all create a class such as this:

```
public class FormatElNumber {
    public static String formatStock(double stock) {
        final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        return nf.format(stock);
    }
}
```

This will output numbers with two decimal places. Secondly you need to add this to the top of your zul file:

```
<?xel-method prefix="c" name="formatStock" class="demo.grid.hierarchy.FormatElNumber"
   signature="java.lang.String formatStock(double)"?>
```

Then when you have a label you can do as follows:

```
<label style="color:red;" value="${c:formatStock(each.averageHigh)}" />
```

More infomration on this technique is available [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Processing_Instructions/xel-method).

**MVVM**

The MVVM is actually easier to implement, you create what's called a Converter, for example (please note this class is untested, but you get the idea).

```
public class NumberFormatConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object coerceToBean(Object val, Component comp, BindContext ctx) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object coerceToUi(Object val, Component comp, BindContext ctx) {

        if(!(val instanceof Integer)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The argument must be a number!");
        }

        final Object tmp = ctx.getConverterArg("length");
        int length = 0;

        if(tmp instanceof Integer) {
            length = (Integer)tmp;
        }

        final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(length);

        return nf.format(val);
    }

}
```

Then all you do in your zul file is specify you would like to use a converter on the value, for example:

```
<label value="@load(vm.message) @converter(vm.myConverter)"/>
```

For more information on this technique you can refer [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Data%20Binding/Converter).

Comment: Cool! I already saw the @converter way to do this, but in some cases we are using the MVC model as you described... Anyway I will sure try it later today. Thanks for your time Tim!

Comment: I have a strange problem with this solution... my code is like you suggested, but when I try to display zul page with `<?xel-method prefix="f" name="formatDouble" class="my.package.ElNumberFormatter"
   signature="java.lang.String formatDouble(BigDecimal)"?>`, zkoss throws error: `org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: file:/C:/Users...w/main/pageIncomeEntry.zul:2:59: Class not found: my.package.ElNumberFormatter` I checked package and class name twice... any thoughts on this?

Comment: Hey Gatekeeper, that's interesting, so it will not work if it is not in a taglib? That may be a bug. If you can reproduce it please can you post it to http://tracker.zkoss.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&requestId=10001 with just a little bit of code to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/EL_Expressions/Core_Methods/formatNumber

```
<?taglib uri="http://www.zkoss.org/dsp/web/core" prefix="c"?>
<zk>
    <label value="${c:formatNumber(2332315231, '$ ###,###,###.00')}" />
</zk>
```